# Adding formatting to excel cell

Tags: xml, excel

XSL: 1.0

I have an XSL script that is inputting a formula into an excel cell that will be filled in dynamically by the formula. The contents of the cell will just be numbers (specifically hours). My goal is to set this new cell to format category of Custom and type "[h]". Ex: Format="[h]"

XSL:

```
<Cell ss:StyleID="cell_data" ss:Formula="=SUM(R[0]C[+1]-R[0]C[-2])">
</Cell>
```

I have tried to add a `ss:Format` with `ss:Type="Number"` to this via a `<Data>` tag but it seems that isnt valid.

The Style is:

```
<Style ss:ID="cell_data">
  <Font ss:Color="#000000" ss:FontName="Calibri"/>
  <Interior ss:Color="#FFCC99" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
  <Borders>
   <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
   <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
   <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
   <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
  </Borders>
</Style>
```

Any advice on how to change this cell would be most helpful.

Comment: So is question is about how to produce a particular output, or about what output would be valid Excel? Also, it would be helpful to *show* how you tried to add a `<Data>`, `ss:Format`, and `ss:Type="Number"`. And, what led you to conclude that your attempt was not valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the format of a Number cell to something other than General, you can do the following.

1) Add a style or modify the current style:

```
    <Style ss:ID="NumberFormatS">
      <NumberFormat ss:Format="[h]" />
    </Style>
```

The `<NumberFormat ss:Format="[h]" />` will force the cell to change its type to Custom [h]. If I was to put [h]:mm, it would have changed the custom type to that value.

The last part is just to set the cell call to the style value:

```
<Cell ss:StyleID="NumberFormatS" ss:Formula="=SUM(R[0]C[+1]-R[0]C[-2])">
</Cell>
```

Once the cell is called, the cell format will be swapped to the format specified from the style.